# Bitcoin-Qt & setgenerate true

Tags: bitcoin-core, miner-configuration, mac, solo-mining, bitcoin.conf

Will Bitcoin-qt mine bitcoins if all I have done is downloaded and installed Bitcoin-qt, and typed in "setgenerate true" into the console?  Are there other steps or configurations necessary?  If so, what are they?

Comment: There are no other steps or configurations necessary. You can type `getmininginfo` to verify the mining process is running. However, it is *extremely unlikely* that you will find a block using this method, because CPU mining for Bitcoin is far too slow for the current difficulty.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the difficulty already, just wanted to confirm the process.

Comment: [Answered here.](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24756/bitcoin-conf-json-rpc-options/24759#24759)

Comment: @NateEldredge Would it be correct to assume that it is a duplicate then?

Comment: Hey Murch, No.  He happened to answer this question in his answer to a question about JSON.  That's because the questions were related, not because they were the same.